# Tomcat monitoring stats

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, jmx

I am working on a script which will monitor Tomcat. I want to report the following:

1. Total active connections
2. Total active user sessions
3. Average memory used by a process at any given time
4. Average request processing time

This script will send a remote call via curl and run a jmx command to get required details e.g:
https://my_host_name/manager/jmxproxy/%20?get=java.lang:type=Threading&att=ThreadCount

Is it possible to get the further stats via this method? As I tried the following and it is throwing exceptions:
https://my_host_name/manager/jmxproxy/%20?get=java.lang:type=Manager&att=activeSessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Manager` has to be further qualified, https://my_host_name/manager/jmxproxy/?get=Catalina:type=Manager,context=/host-manager,host=localhost&att=activeSessions

```
OK - Attribute get 'Catalina:type=Manager,context=/host-manager,host=localhost' - activeSessions = 0
```